# Web server in C gives Segmentation Fault (core dumped) after few refresh

Tags: c, sockets, http

I'm trying to build a web server in C using sockets.
I can send to the client all the files it needs (including big css and js files) and the page loads correctly, at least for several times. After some refreshes though the server closes with "Segmentation fault (core dumped) error". My guess is that I overflow some buffers but I don't know how should I solve it. The function I use to build the answer for the client is this:

```
void response_generator (int conn_fd, char *filename) {

    /* vars needed for finding the length of the file */
    struct stat filestat;
    FILE *fp;
    int fd;
    char header_buff [1024];
    char file_buff [MAX_LEN];
    char filesize[7];

    if ( ((fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY)) < -1) || (fstat(fd, &filestat) < 0) ) {
        printf ("Error in measuring the size of the file");
}

    if (filename == NULL) {
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");
    }

    sprintf (filesize, "%zd", filestat.st_size); // put the file size of buffer, so we can add it to the response header
    fp = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
    printf ("fp is null or filename = 404\n");
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");       
    }

    else if (fp != NULL) {
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: ");
        /* content-length: */
        strcat (header_buff, filesize);
        strcat (header_buff, "\r\n");
        /* content-type: */
        strcat (header_buff, find_content_type (filename));
        /*I use the find_content_type to return the MIME of the file*/
    }

    else {
      strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");   
    }        

    strcat (header_buff, "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
    write (conn_fd, header_buff, strlen(header_buff));

    fread (file_buff, sizeof(char), filestat.st_size + 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    write (conn_fd, file_buff, filestat.st_size);

    close (conn_fd);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding
`header_buff[0] = '\0';  file_buff[0] = '\0'; ` at the end if the function before I close the socket as I thought that there is the problem but it did not work

Comment: Another believe is that because I use threads (for each request I create another thread) it might sometimes send a file before another so it cause conflicts (like sending a js with jquerry syntax before sending the jquerry).

Comment: Both `read()` and `write()` return a value. Use it!